# AJAX based infinite scrolling - does not work for Mysql records sorted in DESC order

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, infinite-scroll

I am using the code snippet available [here](http://www.bewebdeveloper.com/tutorial-about-ajax-scroll-paging-using-jquery-php-and-mysql)

My PHP code is :

```
<?PHP
    /***  This is for bottomless listing of record from a table ****/
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM agency_list ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 5';
   $query = $dbo4->prepare($sql);   // dbo4 coming from config.php
   $query->execute();
   $list = $query->fetchAll();
 ?>
```

The relevant css code is:

```
.content {
    padding: 10px;
    min-height: 100px;
   text-align: center;
}

#loader {
    text-align: center;
    display: none;
}
#items { 
    list-style: none; 
   text-align: left; 
}
#items li { 
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    background: #FFFFFF;    /* original -- f1f0f0*/
    border: 1px solid #999999;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #333333;
 }
 #items li h2 {    
   font-size: 18px;
   padding: 5px;
}

#items li p {
   padding: 5px;
}
```

The java script code (end-less-scroll.js) is as following:

```
var is_loading = false; // initialize is_loading by false to accept new loading
var limit = 5; // limit items per page
$(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
            if (is_loading == false) { // stop loading many times for the same page
                // set is_loading to true to refuse new loading
                is_loading = true;
                // display the waiting loader
                $('#loader').show();
                // execute an ajax query to load more statments
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'load_more.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {last_id:last_id, limit:limit},
                    success:function(data){
                        // now we have the response, so hide the loader
                        $('#loader').hide();
                        // append: add the new statments to the existing data
                        $('#items').append(data);
                        // set is_loading to false to accept new loading
                        is_loading = false;
                    }
                });
            }
       }
    });
});
```

Above code is invoking load_more.php which has following code:

```
<?PHP
    include 'config.php';

    $last_id    =   $_POST['last_id'];
    $limit      =   5; 

    if (isset($_POST['limit'])) 
    {
        $limit  =   intval($_POST['limit']);
    }

    // selecting the items for page params
    try 
    {
        $sql    =   'SELECT * FROM agency_list WHERE id > :last_id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, :limit';
        $query  =   $dbo4->prepare($sql);

        $query->bindParam(':last_id', $last_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $query->bindParam(':limit', $limit, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $query->execute();

        $list   =   $query->fetchAll();
    } 
    catch (PDOException $e) 
    {
        echo 'PDOException : '.  $e->getMessage();
    }

    $last_id = 0;

    foreach ($list as $rs) 
    {
        $last_id = $rs['id'];
        ?>
            <li>
                <h2>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='#'><?PHP echo  '[' .$rs['id'] .'] ' . $rs['agency_nm']; ?></a>
                <img height = "32px" width = "32px" src="images/face_smile_1.png"></h2>

                <blockquote>
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Et non ex maxima parte de tota iudicabis? 
                        Item de contrariis, a quibus ad genera formasque generum venerunt. Sit enim idem caecus, debilis. 
                        Duo Reges: constructio interrete.
                        <BR>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Et non ex maxima parte de tota iudicabis? 
                        Item de contrariis, a quibus ad genera formasque generum venerunt. Sit enim idem caecus, debilis. 
                        Duo Reges: constructio interrete.
                    </p>
                </blockquote>
                <h5>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<?PHP echo $rs['agency_addr_landmark']; ?></h5>
                <h5>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<?PHP echo $rs['agency_city']. ' - ' . $rs['agency_pin'] . ' [' . $rs['agency_state'] . '] ' ; ?></h5>                                            
                <h5>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<?PHP echo $rs['agency_contact_per_1']; ?></h5>

                <h5>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color = "maroon"><?PHP echo $rs['agency_contact_addr1'];?></font></h5>

                <p style="align:right;">
                    <a href="#" class="tags" style="background-color:darkgreen;">Details</a>
                    <a href="#" class="tags" style="background-color:#955251;">Update</a>
                    <a href="#" class="tags" style="background-color:#5B5EA6;">More</a>
                </p>
                <BR>
            </li>
            <BR>
        <?PHP
    }

    if ($last_id != 0) 
    {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">var last_id = '.$last_id.';</script>';
    }

    // sleep for 1 second to see loader, it must be deleted in prodection
    sleep(1);
?>
```

And finally the fetched records are being listed in this div (in HTML file)

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/end-less-scroll.js"></script>

<div class="row">
    <div class="twelve columns">            
        <div class="content">
            <ul id="items">
                <?PHP
                    $last_id = 0;
                    foreach ($list as $rs) 
                    {
                        $last_id = $rs['id']; // keep the last id for the paging
                        ?>
                        <li>
                            <h2>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='#'><?PHP echo  '[' .$rs['id'] .'] ' . $rs['agency_nm']; ?></a><img height = "32px" width = "32px" src="images/face_smile_1.png"></h2>

                            <blockquote>
                                <p>
                                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Et non ex maxima parte de tota iudicabis? Item de contrariis, a quibus ad genera formasque generum venerunt. Sit enim idem caecus, debilis. Duo Reges: constructio interrete.
                                    <BR>
                                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Et non ex maxima parte de tota iudicabis? Item de contrariis, a quibus ad genera formasque generum venerunt. Sit enim idem caecus, debilis. Duo Reges: constructio interrete.
                                </p>
                            </blockquote>
                            <h5>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<?PHP echo $rs['agency_addr_landmark']; ?></h5>
                            <h5>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<?PHP echo $rs['agency_city']. ' - ' . $rs['agency_pin'] . ' [' . $rs['agency_state'] . '] ' ; ?></h5>                                            
                            <h5>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<?PHP echo $rs['agency_contact_per_1']; ?></h5>

                            <h5>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color = "maroon"><?PHP echo $rs['agency_contact_addr1'];?></font></h5>

                            <p style="align:right;">
                                <a href="#" class="tags" style="background-color:darkgreen;">Details</a>
                                <a href="#" class="tags" style="background-color:#955251;">Update</a>
                                <a href="#" class="tags" style="background-color:#5B5EA6;">More</a>
                            </p>
                            <BR>

                        </li>
                        <BR>
                        <?PHP
                    }
                ?>
                <script type="text/javascript">var last_id = <?PHP echo $last_id; ?>;</script>
            </ul>
            <!-- this is the paging loader, now is hidden, it wiil be shown when we scroll to bottom --> 
            <p id="loader"><img src="images/ajax-loader.gif"></p>
        </div><!-- content -->          
        <hr>
    </div>
</div>
```

My problem is that

(1) The code is working perfectly fine if I sort the records by ASC order in both the MySQL queries given. However, if I change the sorting order from ASC (as given in the linked tutorial) to DESC, the logic only lists for 5 records, then first 4, 3, 2, 1 records again and stops work. I know I am doing something very silly in the logic, but unable to find my mistake. Please help me.

(2) Assume that I need to sort by some other column (which is not the PRIMARY key - id being PRIMARY KEY here) e.g. suppose I want to sort the records by agency_nm and the list them using this in the bottom less listing fashion, am I supposed to make some changes in AJAX part (or load_more.php) as well? Sorry but I am not good in AJAX - hence this silly question.

Thanks / Regards to all for your kind help and suggestions.

Comment: Though mentioned in the question statement, let me emphasize that the code works perfectly for sorting order ASC. The code given here is the one which is not working as expected and has the sorting order DESC.

Answer (score 0):

Change the line:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM agency_list WHERE id > :last_id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, :limit';
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM agency_list WHERE id < :last_id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, :limit';
```

All you have to do is change this operator: > to <